# Setting source for Sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using static tool Sonar for my project. Folder structure of mt project is like :

```
src
   com
   plugin
      com
```

My **src** folder has package like **com.a.b** and then **plugin** has **com.c.f**. Point to note is, package doesn't start with **plugin.com.c.f**.

Now when I run Sonar using :

```
   <property name="plugin.sonar.projectName" value="plugin" />
   <property name="plugin.sonar.projectBaseDir" value="../base/src/plugin" />
   <property name="plugin.sonar.sources" value="../../base/src/plugin" />
   <property name="project.sonar.sources" value="src" />                             //line 4
   <!-- property name="project.sonar.sources" value="src, src/plugin" / -->          //line 5
```

It throws, `Caused by: org.sonar.squid.api.AnalysisException: The source directory does not correspond to the package declaration com.c.f`.

So I commented line 4 and used line 5, But then it keeps throwing, DuplicateSourceException when no two file are same in the project(Check thrice).

Is there any other way to do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your directory structure, you will probably want to setup an exclusion rule on the root project, so that the `src/plugin` directory will only be analyzed as part of the `plugin` sub-project, e.g:

```
<property name="project.sonar.sources" value="src"/>
<property name="project.sonar.exclusions" value="src/plugin/**"/>
<property name="plugin.sonar.sources" value="src/plugin"/>
```

Comment: I just did with exclusion and added plugin in another module, will try this if it can be done with exclusion and then adding the folder in same module. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure is complicated. In your case "plugin" is another source directory. If 
you mark "src" as sources, all files under that must be taken as sources. This leads package directory mismatch.   Normal compilation this is not an error. Sonar this is an error.

The directory folder is scanned recursively. When you provide src and src/plugin as sources, this probably taking sources from src/plugin two times.

You could use this an opportunity to clean the build environment(One for main build, another one for dependency).

Comment: how come using src/plugin as source folder makes class duplicate? As class name is full specified name with package.

Comment: It got scanned twice. Once when processing  "src", next time when processing "src/plugin".  (Just a guess.)